# subquery must return only one column

Tags: php, postgresql, subquery

This query runs successfully in `pgAdmin`, but when I transfer it in `zend` I get:
`ERROR: subquery must return only one column...`

Can someone distinguish the problem?

```
  SELECT "trail_history"."new_audit_trail".*,
         (SELECT "admin".list_category_values_new."values"
            FROM "admin".list_category_values_new
           WHERE CAST(seq  AS character varying) = "trail_history"."new_audit_trail"."current_value"
             AND "name" = "trail_history"."new_audit_trail"."name") as "values"
    FROM "trail_history"."new_audit_trail" 
   WHERE (capno LIKE '12101062411001%') 
     AND (recon = '0') 
ORDER BY "date_happened" DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sub-select `SELECT "admin".list_category_values_new."values"...` has nothing that prevents it from returning multiple rows.  You need to use TOP 1 or MAX or something to ensure that only one record comes out of the sub-select.

You can correlate the sub-query so that each record in your main select gets a different single value, but if you're going to use a sub-select it can only return one row per row of output in your main select.

Comment: Confusion of terms here.  The error is that the subquery should return only one *column*, but it selecting more than one.  However, you are correct .. it can only return one row too with the way it is used here.  If the column error is corrected, the row error would be next.

Comment: I assumed @OP's question contained a minor error in terminology.  Clearly the indicated subquery is only returning one column.  The possibility of multiple rows is obviously going to be an issue, however.

Comment: @joel-brown Looks like PostgreSQL got the minor error in terminology: it's standart error message.