# error : subquery must return only one column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, left-join, cross-join

I am getting the error `subquery must return only one column` when I try to run the following query:

```sql
SELECT mat.mat as mat1, sum(stx.total) as sumtotal1,
  (
    SELECT mat.mat  as mat, sum(stx.total) as sumtotal
    FROM stx 
      LEFT JOIN mat ON stx.matid = mat.matid
      LEFT JOIN sale ON stx.saleid = sale.id
    WHERE stx.date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31' 
      AND sale.userid LIKE 'A%'
    GROUP BY mat.mat
  ) AS MyField
FROM stx 
  LEFT JOIN mat ON stx.matid = mat.matid
  LEFT JOIN sale ON stx.saleid = sale.id
WHERE stx.date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31'
  AND sale.userid LIKE 'B%'
GROUP BY mat.mat
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: **@user2431581**, You are defining field `MyField` via a sub query.  When you do that the sub query must only return one value and one field.  You are returning `mat.mat` as well as `sum(stx.total)`.  That is illegal SQL syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [subquery must return only one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673834/subquery-must-return-only-one-column)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put a subquery that returns multiple columns in the `FROM` list and select from it.

A correlated subquery would be a bad idea to begin with. However, your query is not even correlated (no link to outer query) and seems to return multiple rows. This leads to a (possibly very expensive and nonsensical) cross join producing a Cartesian product.

Looks like you really want something like this:

```sql
SELECT m1.mat AS mat1, m1.sumtotal AS sumtotal1
     , m2.mat AS mat2, m2.sumtotal AS sumtotal2
FROM  (
   SELECT mat.mat, sum(stx.total) AS sumtotal
   FROM   stx 
   LEFT   JOIN mat ON mat.matid = stx.matid
   LEFT   JOIN sale ON stx.saleid = sale.id
   WHERE  stx.date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31'
   AND    sale.userid LIKE 'A%'
   GROUP  BY mat.mat
   ) m1
JOIN  (
   SELECT mat.mat, sum(stx.total) AS sumtotal
   FROM   stx 
   LEFT   JOIN mat ON mat.matid = stx.matid
   LEFT   JOIN sale ON sale.id = stx.saleid
   WHERE  stx.date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31' 
   AND    sale.userid LIKE 'B%'
   GROUP  BY mat.mat
   ) m2 USING (mat);
```

Both `LEFT JOIN` are also pointless. The one on `sale` is forced to a `INNER JOIN` by the `WHERE` condition. The one on `mat` seems pointless, since you `GROUP BY mat.mat` - except if you are interested in `mat IS NULL`? (I doubt it.)

The whole query can further simplified to:

```sql
SELECT m.mat
     , sum(x.total) FILTER (WHERE s.userid LIKE 'A%') AS total_a
     , sum(x.total) FILTER (WHERE s.userid LIKE 'B%') AS total_b
FROM   sale s 
JOIN   stx  x ON x.saleid = s.id
JOIN   mat  m ON m.matid = x.matid
WHERE  s.userid LIKE 'ANY ('{A%,B%}')
AND    x.date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Using the aggregate `FILTER` clause (Postgres 9.4+). See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

In Postgres 11 or later, this can be optimized further with the ["starts with" operator **`^@`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) for prefix matching. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

```sql
SELECT m.mat
     , sum(x.total) FILTER (WHERE s.userid ^@ 'A') AS total_a
     , sum(x.total) FILTER (WHERE s.userid ^@ 'B') AS total_b
FROM   sale s 
JOIN   stx  x ON x.saleid = s.id
JOIN   mat  m ON m.matid = x.matid
WHERE  s.userid ^@ ANY ('{A,B}')  
AND    x.date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The `WHERE` condition might get even simpler, depending on your secret data types and indices. Here is an overview over pattern matching operators:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Comment: "Put a subquery that returns multiple columns in the FROM list and select from it.". This! Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if the select is performed against a function that has multiple OUT parameters (but the function doesn't return a record, setof, or any similar type and the function can't be altered)? For example, suppose a function has 2 out parameters, 'hi' and 'lo' -- so that regular usage returns a record tuple like (4, 5). But "select *" would return the results separately as two columns. Now suppose you want to execute that function on multiple columns of the result of some join. Some thing like `select my_func(a.colA, b.colB) from tabA a join tabB b on a.id = b.id`.

Comment: @Mr.F: This is beyond a comment. I suggest you start a new question with the necessary information. You can always link to this one for reference and drop a comment to link to the related question and notify me. There is a solution ...

Comment: Good advice. Here is a [link to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297935/split-function-returned-record-into-multiple-columns).

Comment: Nice Solution 
Saved my Neck 
Thanks Bro

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subquery select statement

```
SELECT mat.mat  as mat, sum(stx.total)  as sumtotal
```

Try this statement

```
SELECT sum(stx.total)  as sumtotal
```

Comment: Try this state ment   SELECT sum(stx.total) as sumtotal

 ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Answer (score 0):

I created `my_func()` which returns two columns `2` and `3` as a subquery as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INT AS $$
BEGIN         -- ↓  ↓
  RETURN (SELECT 2, 3);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But calling `my_func()` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 1: (SELECT 2, 3)
        ^
QUERY:  (SELECT 2, 3)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func() line 3 at RETURN
```

So, I returned only one column `2` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INT AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT 2);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       2
(1 row)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
 my_func
---------
       2
(1 row)
```

Or, I used `row` local variable whose type is `RECORD` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE                        -- ↑ ↑ ↑
  row RECORD; -- Here
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO row FROM (SELECT 2, 3);
  RETURN row; -- ↑
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
 (2,3)
(1 row)
```